# How to add cubed special character in Bash SED command

Tags: regex, bash, sed, character, special-characters

I am using the sed command below to add characters to a list of numbers. In this case I'm trying to add gcm³.

```
sed -ie 's/^//;s/$/ gcm3/' numbers.txt
```

But rather than gcm3 I would like I would like to appear as gcm³. How can I get the proper cubed within sed?

Comment: Doesn't `'s/^//;s/$/ gcm³/'` work?

Comment: And doesn't `s/^//` do nothing?

Comment: Wiktor, indeed it does. Don't I feel dumb! Thank you. Post that as the answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use extended characters in `sed` replacement as is.

You may use

```
sed 's/^//;s/$/ gcm³/' file > outfile
sed -i 's/^//;s/$/ gcm³/' file
```

See [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/HlEXmT):

```
s='23'
sed 's/^//;s/$/ gcm³/' <<< "$s"
# => 23 gcm³
```